# Necessary and sufficient conditions on antecedent for deduction theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, meta-math, metalogic

The deduction theorem for classical predicate logic states that for any set of wffs $\Gamma$ , any **closed** wff $A$, and any wff B, if $\Gamma\cup\{A\}\vdash B$, then $\Gamma\vdash A\implies B$. The condition that $A$ is closed is sufficient, but it is clearly not necessary, i.e., there are wffs with free variables that satisfy the deduction theorem. Are there any known necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$ for the deduction theorem? If not, what are strongest known conditions on $A$?

Here are some definitions: Let $\Sigma$ be a complete and consistent set of axioms/inference rules for predicate calculus. For any set of wffs $\Gamma$, and any wff $A$, we say that $\Gamma\vdash A$ iff there exists a deduction from $\Sigma\cup\Gamma$ to $A$. Additionally, we say that $\Gamma\vDash A$ iff for every interpretation $\mathcal{M}$ and valuation $v$, if $\mathcal{M},v\vDash\Gamma$ then $\mathcal{M},v\vDash A$.

Comment: This depends on what your conventions are for formulas with free variables on the left-hand side of the turnstile? I.e., it is a matter of *definition* and you have to tell us what the definitions your are using say.

Comment: For formulas on the left-hand side of the equation there should be no restrictions other than being well-formed. Other than that, what definitions particularly are you looking for?

Comment: So if you are allowing formulas with free variables in $\Gamma$, what is your definition of $\Gamma \vdash A$? Does $\{x = x\} \vdash y = y$ under your definition?

Comment: I've added some definitions below my question. Hopefully that suffices.

Comment: Basically, in the derivation of $B$ you have to avoid generalization on variables that are free in $A$.

Comment: Details into SC Kleene, [Introduction to Metamathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=HZAjPwAACAAJ) page 90-on.

Comment: The additions to the question don't answer my question, so I'll repeat it. Does $\{ x = x\} \vdash y = y$ under your definitions?

Comment: Yes, $\{x=x\}\vdash y=y$ is true. Because equality is the same under every interpretation,  $\vDash y=y$, and since our set of axioms is complete, it must also be the case that $\vdash y=y$. Hence, it vacuously follows that $\{x=x\}\vdash y=y$ by carrying out the same deduction of $\vdash y=y$.